# Exchange Web Server exception : "Connection failed. Try later."

Tags: iis, exchange

Every time I try to call the server, I get an error code : `ErrorConnectionFailed` with `Connection failed. Try later.` message.

I suspect that it comes from the fact that the credentials of `ExchangeService` are empty. Although I have no idea why. If I create the credentials manually using my windows account login and password, it works fine : `new WebCredentials(login, password, domain);`

I'm very new to IIS, so I might have missed some settings. I enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication.

How can I make it work using `new WebCredentials(CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);` ?